# Ubuntu One sync certain filetype/prefix

Tags: ubuntu-one, file-format

I want to only sync files with a certain prefix in a folder.  Is there some way I can get Ubuntu one to only sync these files or ignore other files?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, there's no good way to exclude certain files in certain directories.
That said, you can ignore certain file types across the board by specifying regexes in: `/etc/xdg/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf`

See the ignore.default part of it.